# How do I install VueJS 3.0 in my Multi-Page App?

Tags: vuejs3

At this moment, I am getting confused day by day. VueJs 2x was fun, we could use it as a library like react (just plug in and get going, on any existing multi page site) by setting up build tool prior to coding... Assuming we're choosing the build tool route.

Has VueJs3 taken the Angular route of focusing more on building a framework more than a library?

I am asking this question, as I have been trying to research on how to set it(VueJs 3x) up on my existing multi-page app as a library. All tutorials seem to inform about setting up a "Vue app" with build tool (vite) using `npm init vue@latest`  like one is building a complete SPA app.

My Multi-Page App is build on Asp.Net Core Razor pages, and all pages are Razor based `.cshtml`, And `npm init vue@latest` assumes one will load the app using the generated `index.html` which is not ideal for my case as pages are `.cshtml`.

### Is there any Tutorials I can use to learn more about using VueJS 3.0 on an existing MPA like a php, django or any other MPA apps?

Comment: Its the first thing mentioned on the official documentation, the isn‘t it? https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/ways-of-using-vue.html

Comment: @Uwe you missed the question. Please read again, I still want a build tool as I want to code in `.vue` file. I don't want to use the global cdn route...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, they are moving towards a framework and you will have to have their CLI to use Vue 3x. You wouldn't be able to use Vue 3x unfortunately on asp.net but you can use Angular.js or Knockout.js (I prefer Angular.js when using asp.net razor pages)

Comment: Thanks. But Angular.JS and KnockoutJS I wouldn't use any of those in 2022.

Comment: I am a Professional React Developer. But I just love VueJs 3.0 and I want to rewrite our Existing Account Management Section of our Multi-Page Site with VueJs 3x.

Comment: You would be able to create a Multi-Page app using Vue cli and if you really want to integrate just that management section of your asp.net app with Vue 3x then you can create your vue management section as a different app and host it as its own application. Create an iframe on your asp.net app and route to that Vue application within the shell. Only solution I can think of to follow the love for Vue, hope it helps!